# Database Controller: Login

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and it is not as easy as PHP. lol.

I'm doing a `DB_Controller` class where I put in the code for the Database connection. I also have a `Login_Model` class where I put the functions for Login.
I'm trying to build a some sort of MVC type concept, so that I can easily code in the future.

However, the code I constructed is not even working. lol. I am having an error which is **InvalidOperationException was Unhandled** - `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll`

Below is my code:

**LoginForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MacoApp
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String user = txtbox_id.Text;
            String pass = txtbox_pin.Text;

            Boolean log = Login_Model.validate_login(user, pass);

            //Login Procedure 
            if (log)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Thank you for logging in!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oops! Incorrect Login");
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

**Login_Model.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MacoApp
{
    class Login_Model
    {
        public static MySqlConnection connect;

        public static bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
        {
            DB_Controller.db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where username=@user and password=@pass";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (login.Read())
            {
                connect.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                connect.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DB_Controller.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MacoApp
{
    class DB_Controller
    {

        public static void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connect;
                String conn = "Server=localhost;Database=macoapp;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here is that `DB_Controller` class initiates and opens a DB connection. But data fetch is happening in Class `Login_Model`, where a new connection object (`public static MySqlConnection connect`) is used for the query. But this **connection object is never initialised or opened before data fetch**.
So the solution is either:

1. Initiate and open the connection in `Login_Model` class or
2. Return the connection you created in `DB_Controller` to `Login_Model` class and use it. **I believe this is what you tried to do.**

Answer (score 0):

The static connection variables in your model and db_controller classes are not related. You never initialize the former, which is most likely what causes the MySQL API to crash.
But please start by figuring out how to get the Message and StackTrace of your exceptions, that will make finding the errors much easier both for yourself and the community.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you're using the connection object.

Try these steps

1. Create the connection and return it from  db_connection()

```cs
public static void db_connection()
{
    ...
    return connect;
}
```

2. Use this connection in MySqlCommand

```cs
public static bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
{
    Login_Model.connect = DB_Controller.db_connection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Login_Model.connect);
}
```